# Couldn't find product without ID using Stripe

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I am trying to complete my payment set up in Ruby but am struggling to gt the order confirmation screen to print. I have set up my partial for the payment as such.

```
<script
  src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
  data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
  data-image="<%= asset_path(@product.image_url) %>"
  data-name="<%= @product.name %>"
  data-description="<%= @product.description %>"
  data-amount="<%= @product.price*100.to_i %>">
  </script>
```

My payment controller.

```
    class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @user = current_user
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    begin
      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        amount: @product.price, # amount in cents, again
        currency: "eur",
        source: token,
        description: params[:stripeEmail]
      )

    if charge.paid
      UserMailer.order_confirmation(@user, @product).deliver_now
      Order.create!(
        :product_id => @product.id,
        :user_id => @user.id,
        :total => @product.price_show
      )
        flash[:success] = "Your payment was processed successfully"
    end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      body = e.json_body
      err = body[:error]
      flash[:error] = "Unfortunately, there was an error processing your payment: #{err[:message]} Your card has not been charged. Please try again."
    end
    redirect_to product_path(@product), notice: "Thank you for your purchase."
  end
end
```

and my routes file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' },
  controllers: {registrations: "user_registrations"}

  resources :products do
    resources :comments
end

post 'payments/create'

  resources :users
  resources :orders, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users, except: [:index]
  get 'simple_pages/about'
  get 'simple_pages/contact'
  root 'simple_pages#landing_page'
  post 'simple_pages/thank_you'
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

The form within product show.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(url: '/payments/create') do |form| %>
  <%= render partial: "shared/stripe_checkout_button" %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag(:product_id, @product.id) %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I try to complete a test payment, I have the action controller pop up with "Couldn't find Product without an ID". I thought this was defined in the create section but I am not sure how to rectify this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What params are received in the controller?. The error that rails is throwing is because it cannot find a ActiveRecord object without its id while doing - `Product.find(params[:product_id])`

Comment: Can you pls share the new.html or the form? as @AlokSwain mentioned it seems that product_id is not set

Comment: Just added now.

Comment: @Jac89, the form looks correct. But the `product` data is not 
Can you check the following 
1) in your form, inspect and see what is the hidden value for `product_id` making sure it has value? 
2) in your controllers' `def create`, print out `params[:product_id]` making sure it is a valid product id

it is more like a data issue, checking the above to make sure

Comment: @wsw Perfect! solved everything there. Thanks once again!

Comment: @Jac89, awesome. 
Do you mind copying the answer and mark your question as resolved. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `:product_id` is not set in your form post,

**1. Quick Solution:**

your form url could be like this:

```
<%= form_with(url: "/payments/create?#{product_id=@product.id}") do |form| %>
```

**2. Better Way:**

configure you routes for payments already has product id:

```
# routes.rb

  resources :products do
    resources :comments
    resources :payments
  end
```

form url:

```
<%= form_with(url: product_payments_path(@product)) do |form| %>
```